# Linq To Sql Intellisense Property Names

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, intellisense

If I had two tables such as this:

```
Profile Table 
-------------
PK ProfileID int
FK AddressPrimaryID int
FK AddressSecondaryID int

Address Table
-------------
PK AddressID int
Address nvarchar
City nvarchar
State nvarchar
Zip nvarchar
```

Notice, the profile has a two relationships to the same table, the address table. When I create my linq to sql class in VS2k8, I add my tables to the dbml. Then I am referencing this profile table in a service and I perform a query to return the first record from the profile repository. No problems there...

I get my single record and I now have intellisense on the object (profile object). I have all my properties plus the Address(object) and Address1(object). Now the Address and Address1 are the actual objects from the relationship built by linq to sql, what I want to know is can I control what the name is for this object in intellisense, so instead of Address and Address1 I could have  AddressPrimary and AddressSecondary for the object name in intellisense. It would just make things clearer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right Click the association on the DBML design surface and click properties.
2. Expand "Child Property".
3. Set the "Name" property to whatever you'd like.